# WPF Grid of buttons, non-percise row count and even spacing

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to duplicate this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WawQc.png, which is a 4*11 grid of 64*64 buttons, made in JavaFX, with WPF

```
<Window x:Class="Kassa.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kassa"
        Title="Kassa" Width="1280" Height="720"  Icon="Resources/Kassa.ico" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">

        <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Width="264" Height="720" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="64"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="64" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="64" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="3" Width="64" Height="64">Kassa</Button>

        </Grid>


</Window>
```

No matter what I try, it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVo2L.png which is horrible. Is there a way to create a button grid in WPF that is normal enough to scale itself properly? Thanks. 10 rows minimum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest ignoring the pixel specificity of your buttons and instead allowing your grid to scale to any size within the window. Your buttons would then auto-size to fit, and you'd just ensure that, at all times, you have a grid of 4x11.

Code similar to the below should get you the desired effect.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="Kassa" Width="1280" Height="720" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Button Margin="0" Grid.Row="0">Kogus</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="3">Kassa</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(EDIT: I've updated this to have your 2 panel layout, with the right panel (your buttons) taking up 20% of available space at all times)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You are missing `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on the main widnow

And if you want to fix the width and height and prevent user from resizing you can add this property `ResizeMode="NoResize"`(also remove the scrollviewer if you want in that case since it wont be really needed if you prevent resizing)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="750" Width="300" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <ScrollViewer  >
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="64"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                <RowDefinition Height="64" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="3">TEST</Button>
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the column width and height from Auto to * if you want the grid buttons to stretch and collapse with the containing window.

```
 <Grid x:Name="container" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="64">Kogus</Button>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: No. the grid should always fill 100% of the window height. NO collapsing columns